# jQuery click event - How to tell if mouse was clicked or enter key was pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have a usability concern on a web site of mine.  I have a set of tabs, each containing a form.  When you click on the tab link, it gives focus to the first textbox in the tab content body.  Mouse-oriented people love this "feature".  The problem is when keyboard-oriented users use the TAB key on their keyboard to go through the tabs.  They hit enter on the tab they want to look at, the click event fires and the tab shows up, but focus is given to the textbox, adjusting their tab order completely.  So when they hit tab again, they want to go to the next tab on the screen, but since focus was moved inside the form, they can't easily get to the next tab using the keyboard.

So, inside the click event I need to determine if they actually clicked on it with a mouse button.  Is this possible?  My first attempt was this:

```
$("#tabs li a").click(function(e) {
  var tab = $(this.href);
  if(e.keyCode != 13)
    $("input:first", tab).focus();
});
```

But `keyCode` is always 0.  The `which` property is also always 0.  Please help!

Comment: You can probably hack around it by putting a .focus() handler on the textbox with a little bit of logic.

Comment: @krasnericalypse  Err, not really.  Once focus is given to the textbox/dropdown it is too late to recover.

Comment: @krasnerocalypse I think I got it... see my answer

Comment: Right on. I was gonna suggest something like that but didn't know if keydown fires before click. Good to know.

Comment: It's a little hacky, but you could probably check if the mouse's position is on top of the tab that was just clicked, using e.pageX and e.pageY.

Comment: @someone The mouse could be over the link if the enter key was used, unfortunately.  Sure it may unlikely, but a bulletproof solution is mandatory in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with, it's surprisingly simple.  I trapped keydown on the tab links, and triggered the click event when keyCode was 13.  Luckily, the [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function allows us to pass extra parameters to the event handler...

```
$("#tabs li a").keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 13) {
    $(this).trigger("click", true);
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

So I just had to change my click handler to receive the new parameter and use it...

```
$("#tabs li a").click(function(e, enterKeyPressed) {
  if(enterKeyPressed)
    alert("Enter key");
  else
    alert("Clicked");
});
```

I put up a [demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2wvF/) as well.  Thanks to everyone who read the question.

Comment: i finish doing the same thing about 4 mins, we are genius =P

Answer (score 1):

An even simpler solution that worked for me was to just check whether there were any mouse coordinates passed with the event.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        //if the event object is passed with mouse coordinates, 
        if(e.screenX && e.screenY){
            //The mouse was clicked
        }else{//The enter key was pressed}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Would a global "focus" variable work, which disable focus on mouse setting after tab usage on a given tab until a mouse is moved to a new block.

This would not be the feature your requesting, but I believe it might give you what your looking for.

eg. mouse hoovers option 5, you hit tab, now you store the 5 in the variable, disallowing focus to 5 until something else been focused on, but as soon something else is focused, global is turned back to -1.

Not cleanest workaround I admit that freely.

Comment: I can't have that many event handlers going on... these forms are big.  This will lock up the browser, for sure.