# How can I check if a submit button is clicked and not an enter press on a page?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Imagine this piece of html:

```
​<form>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit" id="a">
</form>​​​​​​
```

and this piece of Javascript

```
document.getElementById('a').onclick = function (e) {
    alert(e.type);
};​​​​
```

The alert will always say 'click', even if you press enter in the textfield.

How can I check if the button is really clicked?

Comment: Just curious: What different does it make?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery click event - How to tell if mouse was clicked or enter key was pressed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394796/jquery-click-event-how-to-tell-if-mouse-was-clicked-or-enter-key-was-pressed)

Comment: Maybe this will help: [Javascript:Enter key press event][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905222/javascriptenter-key-press-event

Comment: @subirkumarsao I'm creating client-side code for a .Net environment which has a single form element in the entire website, but I need to do something when that precise button is clicked

Comment: @ChrisGessler I think it's the same problem, thank you

Comment: if you inspect the event `(e)` object you will find some alternate properties to evaluate, one of these should prove useful.

Comment: @luckyape Yes, it was a duplicate of the one that Chris mentioned above. Also, this is more than 8 years old, how did you find it?

Comment: wow, could not tell you how i ended up on this question, just rando coffee break browsing

Answer (score 1):

Imagine this piece of html:

```
<form>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="button" id="a">
</form>
```

and this piece of Javascript

```
document.getElementById('a').onclick = function (e) {
    this.form.submit();
};​​​​
```

No confusion will be possible.

There is almost no reason to use `input type="submit"` in modern web applications.

Comment: This isn't semantically correct, buttons are not to be used for submitting forms

Comment: Most things in HTML, CSS, javascript, won't make sense nor allow the building of complex web applications if you see them only as semantic elements. Be practical and keep it simple. Don't forget that in the age of ajax, forms are rarely passive objects just sent to a server. What would be REALLY wrong would be to check in the onClick if the key is an enter...

Comment: @dystroy [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) Everybody with disabled Javascript won't be able to use the form/site.

Comment: I don't see them only as semantic elements, but their semantics are a part of what they are. If you completely ignore the semantics you can just as well go back to table-layouts. In my opinion you should use the right elements for the job unless there are no other options.