# Prevent "enter" keypress form submission but not datalist selction

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, dom-events

A real corner case. I have an HTML form similar to this:

```html
<html>
<script>
function captureEnter(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
</script>
<form>
<datalist id="some-data">
  <option value="option 1">option 1</option>
  <option value="option 2">option 2</option>
  <option value="option 3">option 3</option>
  <option value="option 4">option 4</option>
</datalist>
<input list="some-data" name="hello" onkeydown="captureEnter" />
</form>
</html>
```

You may try on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yookoala/swxysLh5/).

On Firefox, is there any way to differentiate the event of:

1. Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> when you're focusing the text field; and
2. Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> when you're selecting options in datalist?

I want to prevent form submission if the user is doing text input and accidentally pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>. My code works, but now it also stops user from using <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select datalist option.

Chrome doesn't have this problem, but I need this to work on Firefox as well.

Comment: try @chillichief answer from this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30022728/perform-action-when-clicking-html5-datalist-option)

Comment: Thanks. But not the problem I want to solve. I want to prevent form submission in the input field. My code works, but now it prevent the datalist selection.

Comment: try this fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/vikscool/8b1dqvnp/) hope this helps

Comment: @vikscool: Just tried it. The HTML in your code missed the form tag and a submit button. When I add all those back, it didn't work as I wanted. I can simply press "Enter" in the text field to submit form (which I wanted to prevent). You may see it in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yookoala/8b1dqvnp/3/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My final solution: https://jsfiddle.net/yookoala/ya3pcuLd/

Javascript of it:

```javascript
document.getElementById("input").onkeydown = function(e) {
  if ((e.keyCode == 13) && (typeof this.form != "undefined")) {
    // get the element's parent form object
    // capture the parent form submit event and supress it
    this.form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }, {"once": true});
  }
}
```

This will capture the submit event right after the "Enter" keypress. But not affect the "Enter" key when doing datalist selection.