# trigger event on selecting item from datalist, not when typing

Tags: jquery, html, html-datalist

I have a form like this:

```
<input list='data-list' id='list'>
<datalist id='data-list'>
  <option>first</option>
  <option>second</option>
</datalist>
```

The user can select an item from the datalist -or- can type in it's own value. I am connection to a database through a JSON call to a PHP script to fill in other information in the rest of the form. I want this to trigger when a user typed a name in the list-input (so when the content is blurred) OR when the user clicked an option from datalist.

Using `$( ':input#list' ).on( 'change', function...` the function is triggered when the input loses focus, but when an item from the data-list is selected it also waits 'till the input loses focus, I want the event to fire straight away

using `$( ':input#list' ).on( 'input', function...` clicking an item from the datalist triggers the function straight away, which is what I want, but typing will trigger the event as well, with each keystroke, sending a lot of unwanted requests to my PHP script.

I have tried binding an event to the datalist directly, but that didn't work.

I am looking to trigger the function when a user clicks (or uses the keyboard to select) an item from the datalist OR when a user entered a word and moves to the next input.

Comment: when using `$( ':input#list' ).on( 'input', function...` you can insert a delay before send another request and check when delayed if the input value still the same or not

Comment: Scott, that would still trigger the event on every keystroke, which is something I'm trying to avoid. I did find an interesting solution on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30022728/perform-action-when-clicking-html5-datalist-option, which basically only does the JSON call when the input the user is typing is also in the datalist, in addition I could make the call on 'change' when it's not called yet... I also see that link goes to what could be a 'duplicate question', so I might delete/close this one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perform action when clicking HTML5 datalist option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30022728/perform-action-when-clicking-html5-datalist-option)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I went for is a combination of both events...

I keep track of a variable `window.latest_autofill_query` to prevent loading the same thing twice in a row. I have the following `onchange` function, this triggers when a user puts the focus out of the input (tabs out, or clicks elsewhere)

```
$( ':input#list' ).on( 'change', function() {
   var current = $( this ).val();
   if( window.latest_autofill_query != current )
      load_autofill();
} );
```

Then there's another function that keeps track of what the user types, and checks if the value entered is in the datalist. If so, we assume that's what the user wants and the next datalist is queried. This is also triggered when a user clicks an item from the datalist which will always result in the value of the input being present in the datalist and thus immediately triggering the load_autofill:

```
$( ':input#list' ).on( 'input', function(){
   var current = $( this ).val();
   $( 'datalist#data-list option' ).each( function(){
      if( $( this ).text() == current ){
         load_autofill();
         return false;     //* break out of jQuery each loop
   } );
} );
```

the `load_autofill` function keeps track of what it loaded last to prevent double loads. I won't go into the details of this load_autofill 'cause it's very application specific, but the framework is like this:

```
function load_autofill() {
    var current = $( ':input#list' ).val();
    window.latest_autofill_query = current;

    //* ... perform loading of the next datalist
}
```

Now the next datalist will be loaded as soon as a user selected an item from the datalist, but not after every keystroke a user makes, only when the text entered is present in the datalist.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, here is the solution. Basically I want to trigger change event, either by sole input or input+keyup event, so new variable is introduced to track this, with small help of setTimeout.

HTML

```
<input list="search-list" value="" class="form-control search-list custom-select custom-select-sm" placeholder="...">
<datalist id="search-list">
  <!-- filled with javascript, eg: <option value="ISO-8859-1">ISO-8859-1</option> -->
</datalist>
```

JS

```
window.onlyInput = false; // true if selecting
window.timeoutID;
window.timeoutIDs = [];    
$('.search-list')    
.on('focus', function(){        
    console.log('focus');
    onlyInput = false;
    $(this).val(""); // reset input
})
.on('change', function(){        
    console.log('change');
    // YOUR CODE HERE, ex:
    // eg: var text = $(this).val().toLowerCase();     
    // $.ajax ....
    onlyInput = false;
})
.on('keyup', function(){        
    console.log('keyup');        
    onlyInput = false;
    clearTimeoutIDs();
    $(this).trigger('change');
})
.on('input', function(){   
    console.log('input');
    var $that = $(this);
    onlyInput = true;        
    timeoutID = setTimeout(function(){            
        if(onlyInput) {
            $that.trigger('change');
            $that.trigger('blur');
        }            
        onlyInput = false;
    }, 300);
    timeoutIDs.push(timeoutID);
});

function clearTimeoutIDs() {
    $.each(timeoutIDs, function(i, d){
        clearTimeout(d);
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set up two separate event listeners.

One listens for new inputs and checks if the new input corresponds with any of the options on the datalist.

The other listens for when the user enters a word and moves on to the next input.

**Working Example:**

```js
var myForm = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
var myInput = myForm.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
var myDataList = myForm.getElementsByTagName('datalist')[0];
var myOptions = myDataList.getElementsByTagName('option');

function listOptionSelected() {
    var myValue = myInput.value;
    for (var i = 0; i < myOptions.length; i++) {
        if (myOptions[i].value === myValue) {
            console.log('Option Selected: ' + myValue);
        }
    }
}

function typedOptionSelected() {
    var myValue = myInput.value;
    if (myValue !== '') {
        console.log('Option Selected: ' + myInput.value);
    }
}

myInput.addEventListener('input', listOptionSelected, false);
myInput.addEventListener('blur', typedOptionSelected, false);
```

```css
input {
display: block;
margin: 0 0 12px 0;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
<input list='data-list' id='list'>
<datalist id='data-list'>
  <option>first</option>
  <option>second</option>
</datalist>

<input id="next-input" />
</form>
```

Comment: No, this triggers on submitting the form. I'm feeding other datalists in the same form on selecting a value, submit would trigger once the whole form is submitted, that's not useful... (the downvote isn't mine though)

Comment: This is not helpful, and does not work - my browser doesn't display any console messages (because the form is not submitted), and OP wants the event to fire **immediately** after clicking (he may not even have a form).

Comment: I've added a second function which triggers the moment an option from the datalist is selected.