# Angular react to clicking/selecting an datalist option element

Tags: angular

This works and calls the method hhh() when value2 was clicked

```
 <select name="select">
    <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="value2" (click)="hhh()">Value 2</option>
    <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
  </select>
```

This does not call the click event

```
<label>Choose a browser from this list:
<input list="browsers" name="myBrowser" /></label>
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option (click)="hhh()" value="Chrome">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
  <option value="Microsoft Edge">
</datalist>
```

How can I get the click event (or even better the event of selecting an element) in the datalist?

Answer (score 3):

A datalist is not 100% the same as a select, you need to add `(change)/(click)` to the input field. But it's probably not 100% what you are after.

1. Select your item.
2. Submit your item either with an button, a keystroke(Enter) or leave focus on the field.

It goes like this:

***.component.html**

```
<input list="browsers" name="myBrowser" (change)="onSortChange($event)">
<datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
    <option value="Microsoft Edge">
</datalist>
```

***.component.ts**

```
onSortChange(e) {
   this.sort(e.target.value);
}


sort(field: string) {
    switch (field) {
        case 'value1':

        break;
        case 'value2':

        break;
        case 'value3':

        break;
        default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Else you need to implement you own Javascript function like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32205204/7018464).

Comment: There is no select element in datalist. putting the change event to datalist did not result in it being called

Comment: I've updated my answer, wasn't aware that your only wanted it for a datalist.

Comment: Where you able to test this? The method defined in (change) is never executed

Comment: I've tested in a project of mine and in [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/v5iqqLfUglDlZ5aYiYSr?p=info) plunker.

Comment: You are right. Interesting enough the method is only called after leaving focus of the input field. I need the event to fire straight after selecting an element. I will probably go with the JS native method that you linked which seems to do what I need.

Comment: Also, in your example the event fires after entering something in the field (and leaving the field) and not just after selecting an element

Comment: That's totally correct, that's why I linked the JS solution.