# How to show a list items under an input field?

Tags: html, css, listitem

I have an input field as a search bar and when I type something, it filters some data and show it in a list item. But it doesn't show what is exactly below the input, it shows a part of it at the top. How can I fix it?

```
<input type="text" placeholder="{{'home.Search' | translate}}" autofocus="true" required (keyup)="sendMessage($event)" class="font">
        <ul class="list" *ngIf="text" >
          <li *ngFor="let item of rows">
            {{item.title}}
          </li>
        </ul>
```

[image: this is the image before typing]

[image: ang this is after typing]

---

i want the list to be show below the input

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle with also the CSS you have written so far?

Comment: @Alessio i added two images and i should mention that i didn't add any css and i need help to add some css code

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `<datalist>` html5.

Example:

```
<label for="myBrowser">Choose a browser from this list:</label>
<input list="browsers" id="myBrowser" name="myBrowser" />
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
  <option value="Microsoft Edge">
</datalist>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Comment: and how can i use it with *ngFor to show an array items? and how can i implement click event for each item?

Comment: I guess that you're making a web app, angularJS maybe, which I know nothing about, so it's all I can help. Also note that `<datalist>` is useful for making a simple input drop-down suggestion. If you need something more advanced then it may not for you.

Comment: and do you know how can file a function by clicking on datalist items?

Comment: Clicking the datalist items will automatically bring it to the input field. And if it's javascript, I'll try this: Add an id to `<option>` like this `<option value="Chrome" id="selectchrome">` then in my js file `document.getElementById("selectchrome").addEventListener("click",...);`. Or this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30022728/perform-action-when-clicking-html5-datalist-option