# How to detect selected option in datalist when has duplicate option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-datalist

I have a input type text with datalist that contains duplicate option values

```
<input type="text" id="my-input" list="data-list">
<datalist id="data-list">
   <option value="John" data-id="1"></option>
   <option value="George" data-id="2"></option>
   <option value="John" data-id="3"></option>
</datalist>
```

What options i have to get the `data-id` when i select option. For example if i select the the second `John` to get `3` as id. I just found this:

```
$("#data-list option[value='" + $('#my-input').val() + "']").attr('data-id');
```

but if i chose the second john it returns `1` as id, whitch is incorrect.

Comment: Do you have any event handlers on `input` or `datalist`?

Comment: Interesting, but I have a feeling that it might not be possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30022728/perform-action-when-clicking-html5-datalist-option Maybe all you can do is check the `value` after it's changed, which isn't sufficient to determine *which* `option` was clicked

Comment: i have onchange on input field. I have a feelind that u're right(it's not possible), but what option i have for a input with options and that can acccept new values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an index to duplicate option in `datalist`. So you should loop through options and in loop select any option in `datalist` has same `value` and add index to `value` attribute of it.

```
$("datalist option").each(function(){
  var sameOpt = $(this).parent().find("[value='"+this.value+"']:gt(0)");
  sameOpt.val(function(i, val){
    return val+'-'+(sameOpt.index(this)+2);
  }); 
});
```

```js
$("datalist option").each(function(){
  var sameOpt = $(this).parent().find("[value='"+this.value+"']:gt(0)");
  sameOpt.val(function(i, val){
    return val+'-'+(sameOpt.index(this)+2);
  }); 
});

$("#my-input").change(function(){
  var v = $("#data-list option[value='"+this.value+"']").attr('data-id');
  console.log(v);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="my-input" list="data-list">
<datalist id="data-list">
  <option value="John" data-id="1"></option>
  <option value="George" data-id="2"></option>
  <option value="John" data-id="3"></option>
  <option value="George" data-id="4"></option>
  <option value="John" data-id="5"></option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Can I ask the purpose of adding 2 to the index, rather than just using the index? In `(sameOpt.index(this)+2)`

Comment: @CertainPerformance `.index()` return number from `0` but i need from `2`

Answer (score 0):

I think that is just the wrong element for your case. If you want the user to pick an item, you should try a `select` element. There are lots of solutions for that available.

With that said, you could use the `label` attribute for the names, and have unambiguous values in `value`:

```
<option label="John" value="1"></option>
<option label="George" value="2"></option>
<option label="John" value="3"></option>
```

That would present all the options for the user, but the actual value they would see after selecting a John would be either 1 or 3, and not John.