# Why don´´t work onClick on option element

Tags: reactjs

I'm developing a plugin to search streets with elastic search, ok?

I have a datalist to show my options to select.
When I receive info from database I create all html option elemtns and add click event to capture and handle.

But I dont know why not works onClick event that I've added to each option element.

Here is my code EDITED:

```
render() {
    const { value, streets, error, labelError } = this.state;
    return (
        <div className="w-100 d-flex flex-column">
            <div className="plug-search plug-search__content">
                <div className="plug-inner-addon">
                    <input onKeyDown={this.handlePressEnter.bind(this)} onChange={this.handleSearch.bind(this)} type="text" placeholder={PLACEHOLDER} value={value} list="streets" autoComplete="on" />
                    <datalist id="streets">
                        { streets && streets.length > 0 && streets.map((street, index) => {
                            return (
                                <Item street={street} position={index} key={index} />
                            );
                        })}
                    </datalist>
                </div>
                <div className="plug-btn-search plug-btn-search__content">
                    <i onClick={this.handleGetGeometry} className={`icon-search plug-search-icon`}></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            {error &&
                <div className={`plug-error plug-error__content ${(error) ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp'}`}>
                    <label className="plug-label">{labelError}</label>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Now I've created a Item component, but still doesnt work:

```
class Item extends Component {

    clickedOption = (event, index) => {
        console.log('clicked');
        console.log('value: ', event.target.value);
        console.log('index: ', index);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="option" onClick={(event) => this.clickedOption(event, this.props.position)}>
                <option value={this.props.street.nombre} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Item;
```

Comment: Hello, in order to help you, could you post a screenshot of the error?

Comment: Please create an example on CodeSandbox

Comment: In the end react uses DOM. `option` element does not have onclick event. Use `onChange` handler on `input` to implement the logic you need.

Comment: Here is the code in Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/suspicious-austin-1kbhb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, `<datalist />` don't support `onClick` events in his `<options />`, you could see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30022728/perform-action-when-clicking-html5-datalist-option) question, in order to apply an option in this kind of cases. Hope this help.

Comment: I've seen that use onIput to get option value.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Alberto Perez

Solved:

```
clickedOption = (event) => {
    console.log('clicked');
    console.log('value: ', event.target.value);
};

render() {
    const { value, streets, error, labelError } = this.state;
    return (
        <div className="w-100 d-flex flex-column">
            <div className="plug-search plug-search__content">
                <div className="plug-inner-addon">
                    <input onInput={this.clickedOption} onChange={this.handleSearch.bind(this)} type="text" placeholder={PLACEHOLDER} value={value} list="streets" autoComplete="on" />
                    <datalist id="streets">
                        { streets && streets.length > 0 && streets.map((street, index) => {
                            return (
                                <option value={street.nombre} key={index} />
                            );
                        })}
                    </datalist>
                </div>
                <div className="plug-btn-search plug-btn-search__content">
                    <i onClick={this.handleGetGeometry} className={`icon-search plug-search-icon`}></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            {error &&
                <div className={`plug-error plug-error__content ${(error) ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp'}`}>
                    <label className="plug-label">{labelError}</label>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
handleSearch = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            value: e.target.value
        })
    }

render() {
    const { value, streets, error, labelError } = this.state;
    return (
        <div className="w-100 d-flex flex-column">
    <div className="plug-search plug-search__content">
        <div className="plug-inner-addon">
            <input onKeyDown={this.handlePressEnter.bind(this)} onChange={this.handleSearch.bind(this)} type="text" placeholder={"placeholder"} value={value} list="streets" autoComplete="on" />
            <datalist id="streets">
                { streets && streets.length > 0 && streets.map((street, index) => {
                return (
                <div key={index} className="option">
                    <option value={street.nombre} />
                </div>

                );
                })}
            </datalist>
        </div>
        <div className="plug-btn-search plug-btn-search__content">
            <i onClick={this.handleGetGeometry} className={`icon-search plug-search-icon`}></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    {error &&
    <div className={`plug-error plug-error__content ${(error) ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp' }`}>
        <label className="plug-label">{labelError}</label>
    </div>
    }
</div>   
);
}
```