# Are datalists allowed display text and how do you get it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 2 part question relating to the `<datalist>` tag. Firstly - whilst this works in Chrome, is the following valid?

```
<datalist id="key1_list">
<option value="myval1">Disp 1</option>
<option value="myval2">Disp 2</option>
<option value="myval3">Disp 3</option>
</datalist>
```

And if it is, how does one get the selected display text from the `<option>` tag? In Chrome the value is the main text with the `Disp 1` listed as small underneath. Does anyone know a way (in Jquery) to get the `text()` as there doesn't appear to be a `selected` flag listed on the selected option.

Comment: I would think that looking at [documentation for `datalist`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) would be easier, and more trustworthy, than asking random people on the internet. The selected item is stored on the element which uses the `datalist` as its `list` attribute.

Comment: Sure but its the selected `value` - my q is how you get the selected text. And I have looked at this page as well. Thank you though.

Comment: ``$(`option[value="${selectedValue}"]`).text()`` Basically, get the `option` by value and get its text.

Comment: You would get the Selected Value from the Input not the List. If you need more help, please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Consider the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30022728/perform-action-when-clicking-html5-datalist-option

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `input` event. See example:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#myKey_list").on("input", function(event) {
    var val = $(this).val();
    console.log("Input: " + val);
    var opt = $("#key1_list option[value='" + val + "']");
    console.log("Option: " + opt.text());
    $(this).val(opt.text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="myKey_list">Choose from this list:</label>
<input list="key1_list" id="myKey_list" name="myBrowser" />
<datalist id="key1_list">
<option value="myval1">Disp 1</option>
<option value="myval2">Disp 2</option>
<option value="myval3">Disp 3</option>
</datalist>
```

As was mentioned by [Perform action when clicking HTML5 datalist option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30022728/perform-action-when-clicking-html5-datalist-option)

> Due to the lack of events available for `<datalist>` elements, there is no way to get a selection from the suggestions other than watching the input's events (`change`, `input`, etc).

When we identify a `input` we can then change the value based on the Option.

Comment: Sorry this won't work where there are two items in the list with the same value but different ID's - which is an allowed possibility.

Comment: @Antony you did not include that in your example or post. I would suggest that you consider an alternative. Maybe give each list item a unique ID. This is just not a very usable solution as all you can get is the Value that is selected. Have you considered https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ or other solutions like just using Select tag.